# Can not install neo4j 5.6.0 service on windows

Tags: neo4j

I have just uninstalled neo4j-community-4.3.11 and I am attempting to install neo4j-community-5.6.0 community edition on a Windows 10 system.  I also just removed an older version of java and installed SE Development Kit 17.0.6.  I am running as a local administrator.  I see "Invalid command line arguments" and "Access is denied" but neither of those seem accurate descriptions of whatever is going wrong here.  Thanks for any help.

```
C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\bin>neo4j.bat windows-service install --verbose
neo4j 5.6.0
VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
VM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
VM Version: 17.0.6+9-LTS-190
JIT compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
VM Arguments: [-Dbasedir=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0]
Configuration files used (ordered by priority):
C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\conf\neo4j.conf
--------------------
Executing command line: powershell.exe -OutputFormat Text -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Get-Service neo4j | Format-Table -AutoSize
Executing command line: powershell.exe -OutputFormat Text -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command & 'C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\bin\tools\prunsrv-amd64.exe' '//IS//neo4j' '--StartMode=jvm' '--StartMethod=start' '--ServiceUser=LocalSystem' '--StartPath=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0' '--StartParams=--config-dir=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\conf;--home-dir=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0' '--StopMode=jvm' '--StopMethod=stop' '--StopPath=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0' '--Description=Neo4j Graph Database - C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0' '--DisplayName=Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j' '--Jvm=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\server\jvm.dll' '--LogPath=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\logs' '--StdOutput=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\logs\service-out.log' '--StdError=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\logs\service-error.log' '--LogPrefix=neo4j-service' '--Classpath=C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\plugins\*;C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\conf\*;C:\Data\Tools\BloodHound\neo4j-community-5.6.0\lib\*' '--JvmOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC;-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow;-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch;-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions;-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields;-XX:+DisableExplicitGC;-Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=1024;-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true;-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048;-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true;-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256;-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions;-XX:+DebugNonSafepoints;--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED;--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED;--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED;-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true;-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '--Startup=auto' '--StopClass=org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint' '--StartClass=org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint'
[2023-04-08 12:28:31] [error] [ 5948] Invalid command line arguments.
[2023-04-08 12:28:31] [error] [ 5948] Access is denied.
[2023-04-08 12:28:31] [error] [ 5948] Apache Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 1 (failed to parse command line arguments).
[2023-04-08 12:28:31] [error] [ 5948] Access is denied.
org.neo4j.server.startup.BootProcessFailureException: Unexpected service command failure.
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.ProcessManager.waitUntilSuccessful(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.WindowsBootloaderOs$ServiceCommandProcess.postStart(WindowsBootloaderOs.java:146)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.ProcessManager.run(ProcessManager.java:52)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.WindowsBootloaderOs.runProcess(WindowsBootloaderOs.java:285)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.WindowsBootloaderOs.runServiceCommand(WindowsBootloaderOs.java:135)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.WindowsBootloaderOs.installService(WindowsBootloaderOs.java:94)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Bootloader$Dbms.installService(Bootloader.java:529)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.WindowsServiceCommand$Install.execute(WindowsServiceCommand.java:56)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:42)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand.main(Neo4jCommand.java:41)
```